# Why does my php `if` not always work?

Tags: php, webmatrix

I have an intranet website that I've setup with 2 different menus. I use PHP to show the menu based on who is logged in. This is what I've got:

```
    <?php  
        if ($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] == 'CORP\mmm976' || $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] == 'CORP\ibb601' || $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] == 'corp\mmm976'){
            include('AdminMenu.php');
        }else {
            include('Menu.php');
        }
    ?>
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm one of the admins and sometimes the `AdminMenu` isn't available to me? What's going on and how can i fix this so it works 100%?

I did add `<p class="White"><?php echo $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']; ?></p>` to the page and then while the name is showing it works fine, but if I apply a style where the name is not showing, it stops working 100%. It'll be hit or miss as to whether it'll give me the `AdminMenu`.

I already have Windows Authentication on and Anonymous Authentication off. `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` has a value it just doesn't always use it unless I'm printing it on the page.

**EDIT**

I just had an instance where I have the page setup to show my username. I was on a different page for about 20 - 30 minutes and when I came back it did not display my username and did not give me the `AdminMenu`. When I then navigated to my main page (where I'm able to use asp.net to see who's logged in) and then went back it again displayed my username and the `AdminMenu`.

**EDIT2**

I thought I figured it out.

It wasn't that the `if` wasn't always working it's that my username wasn't being sent the server every time that I refreshed the page. When I would refresh and my username wasn't sent the `if` did what it was supposed to and didn't give me the admin menu. To get around this I ended up using the global `$_COOKIE` variable to keep my username (with a duration of 7 days):

```
<?php setcookie("UserName",$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],time() + (60*60*24*7)); ?>
```

Then had to add that into the `if` since it can't be used till after you refresh the first time:

```
    <?php
        $AdminUsers = array("CORP\User1","CORP\User2");
        if  (in_array($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],$AdminUsers,TRUE) || in_array($_COOKIE['UserName'],$AdminUsers,TRUE))
        {

            include('AdminMenu.php');
        }
        else
        {
            include('Menu.php');
        }
    ?>
```

However I have discovered today that the `$_COOKIE` value isn't being kept. I don't yet know why. I have the `<?php setcookie("UserName",$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],time() + (60*60*24*7)); ?>` as the first line in the file, then the rest of my code. So that it's the first thing run when navigating to the page.

If I leave the page up, but not active, and then come back does it reset the `$_COOKIE`? I was using `var_dump` to see what was there. When I don't get the Admin Menu, there is no result in the `$_COOKIE` array with the name of "UserName". It just goes away after a while even though I have it set to expire a week after being set.

Comment: Set cookies (I *think*) doesn't actually do anything until the end of the script so you can't set a new cookie value and then read from that cookie value on the same script, in that order....

Comment: @Martin That's why I have it as an `if` `or`. It checks `if` the `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` `or` `$_COOKIE['UserName']` has a match to one of the usernames in the array. And the documentation says that it must be sent before any output from my script. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: but you're calling to check if the cookie value; are you calling the cookie value at least one page load *after* you've (potentially) set the cookie value?

Comment: @Martin I'm calling it at page load, whether that's the first page load or a refresh. When I call it the first time the page is loaded it doesn't exist, but the `AUTH_USER` does (and is set) so the `if` is still true.

Comment: Can you try using sessions to store the data instead of cookies? does the same inconsistent behaviour occur with sessions vs cookies? (they approach the same issue from different angles). It would also be a good idea to fill out the rest of the options on the `setcookie` function, such as clarifying domain, etc. simply for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Martin I have not tried using any about sessions. I'll have to look into them, never used them before. Still fairly new to PHP.

Comment: sessions are like cookies but the data is stored on the server, only the reference is stored in a cookie on the client. You can also run an `if` statement and check that `setcookie` function returns true, so you know when a cookie is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up having to do:

Before the rest of the code for the page:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['UserName']))
    {
        setcookie("UserName",$_COOKIE['UserName'],time() + (60*60*24*7));
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie("UserName",$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],time() + (60*60*24*7));    
    }
?>
```

That will determine it the `$_COOKIE` is already set for the UserName.

Then in the body of the HTML I have this:

```
    <?php
        $AdminUsers = array("CORP\User1","CORP\User2");
        if  (in_array($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'],$AdminUsers,TRUE) || in_array($_COOKIE['UserName'],$AdminUsers,TRUE))
        {

            include('AdminMenu.php');
        }
        else
        {
            include('Menu.php');
        }
    ?>
```

The `$AdminUsers` is an array that holds the usernames of all the admins. Then I check to see if either `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` or `$_COOKIE['UserName']` matches one of the users in the array. So far I've been able to leave the page open for a whole weekend and still come back and refresh with the Admin Menu staying in place for me.